# Заполнить выпадающий список

Tags: javascript

Не получается заполнить выпадающий список "task" массивом

```
(async function main() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(proxyurl + url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
        });

        let result = await response.json();
        for (let i = 0; i <= result.length; i++)
            console.log(result[i].id);
        id = result[i].id
        document.getElementById('arr').textContent = (id)

        let urlIssue = 'https://sad.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/issues/' + id + '?fields=summary,description';


        let objSel = document.getElementById('task')
        objSel.options[i] = new Option(id);

    } catch (err) {
        //console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вы потеряли фигурные скобки `{}` для вашего цикла.

Comment: То не важно, там одна строчка выполняется

Comment: Нет, это важно. Из-за этого и не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вам уже написали нужны скобки. Если кратко то цикл должен быть например таким.

```
const objSel = document.getElementById('task')
const arr = document.getElementById('arr')
for (let i = 0; i <= result.length; i++){
        const id = result[i].id
        arr.textContent = id
        objSel.options[i] = new Option(id);
}
```